Adjacency Multilist for a Directed graph (digraph)
This is borrowed from Horowitz, Sahni, and Mehta's Fundamentals of Data Structures in C++, 1st Edition, Exercise 2(d) on page 343. The task is to generate an adjacency multilist for the digraph G5, as shown below.

The attached image also shows my attempt at the solution for constructing the adjacency multilist representation of a directed graph (digraph) G5. Each node of the adjacency multilist is made of two vertices which constitute the edge of the graph, and two lists which are adjacency lists for each of the two nodes to which the edge is incident. Is my solution correct?
